# SQL query issue COUNT()

Tags: sql, sql-server, count

I tried set the count of rows which have a specific value for multiple columns in the same query

this is what I have tried...

```
SELECT 
        COUNT(*) AS house_with_12_rooms,
        COUNT(*) AS house_with_4_rooms
FROM housetable
WHERE num_of_rooms = "twelve"
   OR num_of_rooms = "four"
```

since there are 157 rows with houses with 12 rooms and 1 row with houses with 4 rooms the result adds up the counts in the result table RATHER THAN placing 157 and 1 respectively.

```
Row house_with_12_rooms house_with_4_rooms  
1   158                 158
```

Could someone give me a clue on how to set up the query properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN num_of_rooms = 'twelve' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS house_with_12_rooms,
       SUM(CASE WHEN num_of_rooms = 'four' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS house_with_4_rooms
FROM housetable
WHERE num_of_rooms IN ('twelve', 'four')
```

Comment: I'll do some reading on conditional aggregation. Thanks, amigo.